# How check if exist a path between two nodes - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the database:

```
Node(nno,color) 
edge(eno,head,tail,weight,gno)
graph(gno,gname)
```

[image]

bold here represents primary key
and the graphh is directed: head -> tail

how can I build  a trigger to check whether or not , with each insert of a node to the graph , the graph is connected? meaning there is a path between every two nodes
How do I even check if there is path between each two nodes ?

I  am using postgreSQL

Comment: your question is totally messed up

Comment: Are there going to be updates and deletions?

Comment: search for 'directed graph find path' for information that may be useful to do what you want.

Comment: Look here - maybe you will find something useful http://www.slideshare.net/quipo/rdbms-in-the-social-networks-age

Comment: **Please** show sample data (create table and insert statements). In general for this kind of problem you want a *recursive CTE*.

Comment: Your nodes does not belong to a (single) graph with this shema. You should move the `gno` reference column from the `egde` table to the `node` table to make possible your request. With this shema, you cannot search for orphaned nodes by definition.

Comment: Like @Craig said, you want a recursive CTE. The relevant [documentaion](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html) even uses graph traversal as an example.

Comment: And please don't post sample data as screen shots. Post them as (formatted) text or even better: post them as SQL `insert` statements, or create a sample on http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

This is an X-Y problem, and most likely unworkable using a trigger: If referential integrity is to be maintained with foreign keys (definitely desirable) then by definition the insertion of a node will create a disconnected graph, and be rejected.

The solution is to have a stored procedure through which all inserts to all three tables are passed, and which only accepts *connected* graph additions.

Given the assumption that a given graph is already connected, then for an extension to a given graph to be accepted it is sufficient for every node in the extension to be connected to any one node in the existing graph.